# The tiger came upon the hunter. Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

I thought it would be came *at* the hunter.
Just like: 
Come *at* me bro!

Comment: Aww...come *to* me!

Comment: Right. Got it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's correct.

There are several different words that could be used, each with a different meaning.

But here's a hypothetical: What if the hunter is actually dead, and the tiger discovers the body? In that case *the tiger came* ***at*** *the hunter* wouldn't make much sense. (Because to **come at** something implies attacking it, and the tiger wouldn't attack a corpse.)

In the case of **came upon**, it just means that the tiger *discovered* the hunter. It could also be phrased as **stumbled upon**.

And, actually, there's nothing to prevent the tiger from **coming upon** the hunter, realizing that it's hungry, and *then* **coming at** the hunter afterwards.